# WSO2IS 5.10.0 - Configuring RootPartition by deployment.toml

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm making an integration of WSO2IS with Ldap and I couldn't find where I can configure RootPartition property from tenant-mgt.xml file on deployment.toml.

Because I need to change from:

```
<Property name="RootPartition">dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
```

To:

```
<Property name="RootPartition">dc=wso2,dc=com</Property>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following configuration in the `deplyment.toml` file.

```
[tenant_manager.ldap.properties]
RootPartition = "dc=wso2,dc=com"
```

Refer to the following resources to understand how each toml configuration is formed.

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRWvtcV1T94&t=0s
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WqZhUoK77I&feature=youtu.be